# setting the emacs theme on startup without the interactive mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using the following snippet to set the theme on Emacs startup.

```
(load-theme 'sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties)
```

However it also asks me for confirmation that this will load some lisp code, how do I turn off this confirmation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `load-theme` with a non-nil `NOCONFIRM` arg.

`C-h f load-theme` tells you that `(load-theme 'sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties t)` should load the theme without asking for confirmation:

```
,----
| load-theme is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `custom.el'.
| 
| (load-theme THEME &optional NO-CONFIRM NO-ENABLE)
| 
| Load Custom theme named THEME from its file.
| The theme file is named THEME-theme.el, in one of the directories
| specified by `custom-theme-load-path'.
| 
| If the theme is not considered safe by `custom-safe-themes',
| prompt the user for confirmation before loading it.  But if
| optional arg NO-CONFIRM is non-nil, load the theme without
| prompting.
| 
| Normally, this function also enables THEME.  If optional arg
| NO-ENABLE is non-nil, load the theme but don't enable it, unless
| the theme was already enabled.
| 
| This function is normally called through Customize when setting
| `custom-enabled-themes'.  If used directly in your init file, it
| should be called with a non-nil NO-CONFIRM argument, or after
| `custom-safe-themes' has been loaded.
| 
| Return t if THEME was successfully loaded, nil otherwise.
`----
```

You should learn to ***ask Emacs first***.  `C-h f` is the least you should know and use, before asking something so simple here.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I didnt know abt C-h f, will use it hence forth.

Comment: The solution is actually `(load-theme 'sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties t)`. Without prepending a quote to the theme, I get the error: "Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties)"